# how to get master version to develop in remote repository

Tags: git, git-revert

I have a remote repository with some commits and pushs, but I need to undo all and bring master to develop repo.

$ git log --oneline
4000708 (HEAD -> develop, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Initial Commit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+replace+branch

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this with the following commands:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git reset --hard master
$ git push origin --force
```

If you have any better or different solution, please let me know :D

Peace!